# Does Liferay allow a different color scheme per user?

Tags: liferay, color-scheme, liferay-theme

I'm implementing a function that allows user to switch between two different color schemes. However, it seems to me that the color scheme in Liferay is per system/portal, not per user. So if a user change it (I can give every user permission to do that), it'll change for all users. Am I understanding it correctly?

If that's the case, what's the best way to implement the function?

What I have in mind now is that, I could add a Custom Field for each user, to store one's selection of color scheme; but I'm not sure what to do next. Looks like that I could not change the color scheme system-wide such that `ThemeDisplay` can use it to render the pages, because that'll change it for all other users. Is it possible to apply the user-specific color scheme while rendering each page?

---

update: It seems that under `theme/_diffs/templates/init.ftl`, there's a way to achieve this by modifying the following line,

```
<#assign css_class = theme_display.getColorScheme().getCssClass() + " yui3-skin-sam" />
```

What we need is to retrieve the user-specific color scheme's Css class, and replace `theme_display.getColorScheme().getCssClass()` with that.

Will test the idea tomorrow.

Comment: It does work, but I found the following approach and decided to follow it: http://www.liferay.com/web/bradley.wood/blog/-/blogs/12052103

Comment: If possible can you answer this question and also mark it as an answer so that it is resolved and will help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under theme/_diffs/templates/init.ftl, there's a way to achieve this by modifying the following line,

<#assign css_class = theme_display.getColorScheme().getCssClass() + " yui3-skin-sam" />
What we need is to retrieve the user-specific color scheme's Css class, and replace theme_display.getColorScheme().getCssClass() with that.